# How to seed stored procedure in entity framework 7 using code first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

we are in a process of making a new application in .Net using entity framework and code first.

the question we currently have  is that is there a way to write all stored procedures in a specific file and run/execute them whenever a new Database is created .

main idea is to write some logic in the Seed method and read data from txt file and execute those st. procedures.

kindly guide if there is any other possible method which is better or a bit more elegant. and also whether this approach of running st. procedure is advisable or not.
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did what you're thinking about doing in the seed method.  You have to write the SQL a certain way for it to work without errors.

My SQL files look like this.

```
DECLARE @CreateOrAlter VARCHAR(255)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'usp_ProcName')
BEGIN
    SET @CreateOrAlter = 'ALTER PROCEDURE '
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @CreateOrAlter = 'CREATE PROCEDURE '
END
    EXEC (@CreateOrAlter + 
           '[dbo].[usp_ProcName]
            (
                @Param INT
            )
            AS
            BEGIN
                SELECT * FROM dbo.Table where Field = @Param
            END
            '
    )
```

Then in your seed you call

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(queryString));
```